# Bayesian network probability diamond shape

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-network

[image]

I am looking to find $P(A=0,D=1)$.

We will have something like $(0.5)(.......)$

The dots are the following:

$P(D=1|C=0,B=0)*P(C=0,B=0|A=1) + \dots + P(D=1|C=1,B=1)*P(C=1,B=1|A=1)$

How am I supposed to find $P(C=0,B=0|A=1)$, and is this the correct approach?

Comment: Are the variables supposed to be binary variables, i.e. assuming only values in {0,1}?

Comment: Yes sorry they are only 0 , 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The joint probability factors as follows,

$P_{A,B,C,D} = P_A\cdot P_{B|A}\cdot P_{C|A}\cdot P_{D|B,C}.$

The marginal probability $P_{A,D}$ is computed as follows:

$P_{A,D} (a,d) = \sum_{b\in B}\sum_{c\in C} P_{A,B,C,D}(a,b,c,d).$

Its just a lengthy calculation.

Add: For $P_{B,C|A}(0,0|1)$ you calculate

$$P_{A,B,C}(1,0,0)/P_A(1)$$

where $P_{A,B,C}(a,b,c) = \sum_{d\in D} P_{A,B,C,D}(a,b,c,d)$.

Comment: Can you maybe do one example of what the calculation would be? how do I find $P(C=0,B=0|A=1)$?

Comment: Aren't you supposing some independence assumptions with the factorization, e.g. $P(B,C|A)=P(B|A)P(C|A)$?

Comment: Doesn't help much.

Comment: how did  you obtain the factorization of the joint distribution? Is it trivial?

Comment: Its just according to the underlying graph.

Comment: At the moment I think that the information about the marginals in the graph is not enough to provide that factoring, but probably the authors did intend your interpretation, otherwise the solution probably would not be unique.

Comment: The information provided in the graph is exactly what you need to establish the joint probability distribution!